# Option with google materialized chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm writing a html page with a single chart using google api.
The chart is LINE type end with 3 CategoryFilter.

If i set the chart option the option value aren't used in my chart:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','corechart', 'controls','table', 'gauge']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard_CP_DIM_TAB);

        function drawDashboard_CP_DIM_TAB() {
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div_CP_DIM_TAB'));

            var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                ...
            });

            var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
              ...
            });

            var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                ...
            });

            var categoryPicker3 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                    ...
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
              'chartType': 'Line',
              'containerId': 'chart_div_CP_DIM_TAB',
              'options': {
                'title':'Title',
                'legend': 'none',
                'pieSliceText': 'label',
                'vAxis': {'gridlines':{'color': 'green'}, 'format' : 'none'}
              },
              'view': {'columns': [0, 4]}
            });

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Data','Istanza' ,'Owner', 'Tabella', 'DimensioneTabella']
                ,[new Date(2012,06-1,30),'DBMW1','DB_AUDIT','AUD$_HISTORY',16000000.9]
                ...
                ,[new Date(2012,09-1,01),'DBMW1','DB_AUDIT','AUD$_HISTORY',28000000.2]
            ]);

            dashboard.bind(slider, categoryPicker1).bind(categoryPicker1, categoryPicker2).bind(categoryPicker2, categoryPicker3).bind(categoryPicker3, [chart]);

            dashboard.draw(data);
        }


    </script>



    <div id="dashboard_div_CP_DIM_TAB">
        <h2>Tabelle con dimensione > 10MB</h2>  
        <div id="catPicker_CP_DIM_TAB1"></div>
        <div id="catPicker_CP_DIM_TAB2"></div>
        <div id="catPicker_CP_DIM_TAB3"></div>
        <div id="slider_CP_DIM_TAB"></div>
        <div id="chart_div_CP_DIM_TAB" width="100%"></div>      
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

in particular the problem is with this line

```
              'options': {
                'title':'Title',
                'legend': 'none',
                'pieSliceText': 'label',
                'vAxis': {'gridlines':{'color': 'green'}, 'format' : 'none'}
              },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*first*, when using *material* charts, the `options` need to be *converted*

each *material* package has a converter...

`google.chart.Line.convertOptions`

*next*, the options are a little different for *material*

`'title'` is a property of the option for `'chart'` -- `chart.title`

and need to use the `'position'` property of the `'legend'` option -- `legend.position`

e.g.

```
'options': google.charts.Line.convertOptions({
  'chart': {
    'title':'Title',
  },
  'legend': {
    'position':'none'
  },
  'pieSliceText': 'label',
  'vAxis': {'gridlines':{'color': 'green'}, 'format' : 'none'}
}),
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','corechart', 'controls','table', 'gauge', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard_CP_DIM_TAB);

function drawDashboard_CP_DIM_TAB() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Data','Istanza' ,'Owner', 'Tabella', 'DimensioneTabella']
      ,[new Date(2012,06-1,30),'DBMW1','DB_AUDIT','AUD$_HISTORY',16000000.9]
      ,[new Date(2012,09-1,01),'DBMW1','DB_AUDIT','AUD$_HISTORY',28000000.2]
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Line',
    'containerId': 'chart-container',
    'dataTable': data,
    'options': google.charts.Line.convertOptions({
      'chart': {
        'title':'Title',
      },
      'legend': {
        'position':'none'
      },
      'pieSliceText': 'label',
      'vAxis': {'gridlines':{'color': 'green'}, 'format' : 'none'}
    }),
    'view': {'columns': [0, 4]}
  });
  chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
```